# How to filter your jquery autocomplete data while typing

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

So far I have the following

```
var aCleanData = ['aaa','aab','faa','fff','ffb','fgh','mmm','maa'];

$('#my-input').autocomplete({
    source:aCleanData,
    minLength:2
});
```

Currently if you type `aa`, `aaa,aab,faa,maa` will show.

What I would like to do is when the user types `ff` the data that is shown will be the `fff,ffb` data.

Basically, only what is typed should be matched from the first character onwards.

This should be recursive. When user types `fg`, `fff,ffb` should disapear and only `fgh` should appear.

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE:

p.s. See what I mean here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default

Type `sc` and you'll see more than just the data beginning with sc.

Comment: Which autocomplete are you using?  The one from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete should perform as you want

Comment: That's the one and its performing as described above.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm using the ui autocomplete. Is that the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible solution to get only results starting with the input value is to check the array elements before search by yourself:

```
var aCleanData = ['aaa','aab','faa','fff','ffb','fgh','mmm','maa'];
$('#my-input').autocomplete({
    source: aCleanData,
    minLength: 2,
    search: function(oEvent, oUi) {
        // get current input value
        var sValue = $(oEvent.target).val();
        // init new search array
        var aSearch = [];
        // for each element in the main array ...
        $(aCleanData).each(function(iIndex, sElement) {
            // ... if element starts with input value ...
            if (sElement.substr(0, sValue.length) == sValue) {
                // ... add element
                aSearch.push(sElement);
            }
        });
        // change search array
        $(this).autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);
    }
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCuas/).

Comment: I like the fact you have kept the hungarian notation style - detail is everything!

Comment: @scessor I am trying to add a default value for all searchs . eg; inside of each function I add else if(sElement.value === 'SMTHNG_DEFAULT') aSearch,push(sElement); but it does not pick my default value up on autocomplete and not shown in my dropdown list. Do you have any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the source for autocomplete, you have a few options.  You could write your own pasrer method that returns what you need and set it as the callback source.  This is probably the more "correct" way to do it.

The faster way is to simply add the following line AFTER you include the ui source:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex=function(){ 
    return '[^|\s]' + $value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");   
};
```

If you care how this works (or should work, I have not tested):

The original code extends the ui.autocomplete with 2 static functions:

```
$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
escapeRegex: function( value ) {
    return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
},
filter: function(array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
    return $.grep( array, function(value) {
        return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
    });
}
});
```

All you should need to do is change what escapeRegex returns to search for the beginning if words only.  By setting the value of escapeRegex to return `'[^|\s]'` in front of the original return, we are saying "Look for the work with a space in front or is the beginning of a line"

Comment: Thanks for the post. I found the search key option @scessor suggested as a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the *jQuery UI - Autocomplete*. The one searching type is not the same way that you want to do. But [this one](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) is may be cover for your need.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they are now the same thing: Quote taken from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ "This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. Its successor is part of jQuery UI" This is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Simply way you can use this technique :

```
    const autocompleteFilter = function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( <array>, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
        };

    $("#From").autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteFilter,
        select: function(event, selectedItem) {
            selectedItem = splitValue(selectedItem.item.value, 3);
            if (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.text;
            } else 
                return false;
        },
    });
```