# jQuery autocomplete: downsize list on value input field

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I filter the list when 1 of the parameters is given (in a different field than the search field). For example, the user specifies the group ="Test" and start searching in the #ContactPerson field. I want only the records where "group":"Test" showing up.

```
   ("#ContactPerson").autocomplete({
              source: [{"value":"XYZ","name":"ZJL","group":"Test"},...]
    ...
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/71puvk59/

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734554/how-to-filter-your-jquery-autocomplete-data-while-typing#answer-7736994](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734554/how-to-filter-your-jquery-autocomplete-data-while-typing#answer-7736994)

Comment: I tried to adapt this solution to my problem, this is what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/71puvk59/ When entering Test in the first field, only 1 record can show up in the autocomplete list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734554/how-to-filter-your-jquery-autocomplete-data-while-typing#answer-7736994) you can override the search function and apply all your filters.

In your case:

```
 var source = [
    {"value": "JL", "name": "JL", "group": "Test"},
    {"value": "MV", "name": "MV", "group": "Family"}
];

$('#ContactPerson').autocomplete({
    source: source,
    search: function (oEvent, oUi) {
        // get current input value
        var sValue = $(oEvent.target).val();

        //groupValue
        var groupValue = $("#group").val();

        // init new search array
        var aSearch = [];

        // for each element in the source array ...
        $(source).each(function (iIndex, sElement) {

            var groupFilterMatch = ((groupValue && sElement.group.indexOf(groupValue) != -1) || !groupValue);
            var nameFilterMatch = sElement.name.indexOf(sValue) != -1;

            // ... APPLY YOUR FILTERS HERE
            //Example: filter group, if it is defined, and filter name
            if (groupFilterMatch && nameFilterMatch) {
                // add element
                aSearch.push(sElement);
            }
        });

        // change search array
        $(this).autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/91Lj5nxx/

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! Do you know how you can make it NOT case-sensitive?

Comment: You're Welcome. To make case-insensitive change ```sElement.name.indexOf(sValue)``` to ```sElement.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase())```